# Synchronizing date and time across multiple Docker containers

Tags: python, docker, date, time, ntp

I have a number of services inside of a Docker Compose right now, and I want to synchronize time between all of them. The catch being, I want to be able to "rewind time" in a sense, and have all the container's times synchronized and **set** to an arbitrary date and time in the past (exact time doesn't matter) so to each container, it is that date and time. It is important that all of the Docker containers are perfectly synchronized, since some of the functions used are based on the current date and time. As an example, containers `A` and `B` would both think it is 1/1/2020, even though it is not on the host system.

My first idea was to use an `NTP` container, and have each container connect to it to get the time. The issue is, I don't see a way to set the date and time in the past with `NTP`.

Another idea was to set the time manually for each container on startup, but this runs into the issue that each container won't be done spinning-up at the same time necessarily, leading to a time difference of a few seconds which breaks everything.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "perfectly synchronized".  It is not possible to "perfectly" sync distributed systems.  You could use NTP by setting the master server's clock manually with a script (but it will not work "perfectly")

Comment: @Andrew Perfectly may have been the wrong word here - I mean to be as synchronized as possible. Does NTP support setting dates and times in the past?

Comment: NTP has limits (500ppm?), so you'd better define it

Comment: As long as they are within a second of each other, that should be fine.

Comment: 1 whole second is a long time in NTP; if you can stand 1 second, that might cover leap seconds and NTP steps